# SparkPost send mail exception

Tags: android, sparkpost

Sparkpost send mail - I have put jar file of spark post and following the same as provided by sparkpost developers but not able to send email .

```
    final String API_KEY = "xxxx"; 
    sparky.sendMessage("xyz@abc.com",  // from email
    "xxx@gmail.com",                   // to email
    "The subject of the message",      // subject of email
    "The text part of the email",      // text of email body
    "<b>The HTML part of the email</b>"); // Html text of email body


But getting this exception

    com.sparkpost.exception.SparkPostErrorServerResponseException: Unexpected server response ContentType(null) from https://api.sparkpost.com/api/v1/URI [scheme=null, userInfo=null, host=null, port=-1, path=transmissions, queryParams=[num_rcpt_errors=0], fragment=null] contentLength(0)
        at com.sparkpost.transport.RestConnection.receiveErrorResponse(RestConnection.java:326)
        at com.sparkpost.transport.RestConnection.receiveResponse(RestConnection.java:235)
        at com.sparkpost.transport.RestConnection.doHttpMethod(RestConnection.java:390)
        at com.sparkpost.transport.RestConnection.post(RestConnection.java:433)
        at com.sparkpost.resources.ResourceTransmissions.createTransmission(ResourceTransmissions.java:40)
        at com.sparkpost.resources.ResourceTransmissions.create(ResourceTransmissions.java:27)
        at com.sparkpost.Client.sendMessage(Client.java:115)
        at com.sparkpost.Client.sendMessage(Client.java:90)
        at mail.SendMail$1.run(SendMail.java:60)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try once with maven or gradle dependencies inspite of using jar . Mine is resolved when i use gradle from jcenter repository.